# wildcard DNS not found only from some desktops

Tags: domain-name-system, debian, apache2

We built an easy website with a form and a thanks page: http://healthcity.giveitatry.nl/ . This works like a glove on our computers. Using a CMS the admin of the site can create several of these forms, for example sportsclubx.giveitatry.nl or sportsunlimited.giveitatry.nl (these last 2 are examples. not yet made).

To get the subdomains to work we have 2 DNS A-records:

```
 A  *.giveitatry.nl 5.157.80.226
 A  giveitatry.nl 5.157.80.226
```

And on the server we have the following Virtual host:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
            DocumentRoot "/var/www/giveitatry"
            ServerName giveitatry.nl
            ServerAlias *.giveitatry.nl
            <Directory "/var/www/giveitatry">
                allow from all
                Options +Indexes
                AllowOverride All
            </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

On all our computers but one in our office we can go to the url using several browsers and even using `ping` etc... But there is one MAC that gets `SERVER NOT FOUND`. We have flushed every DNS cache we could think of on his computer but that didnt's change anything. Several computers belonging to our customer have the same error or `DNS not found` or `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`. It appears as though they never get to our server's IP.

Ill add my entire Virtual host config if maybe someone needs it:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/giveitatry
    </VirtualHost>



    <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/xxxxxx"
    ServerName xxxxxx.nl
    ServerAlias www.xxxxx.nl
    <Directory "/var/www/xxxxx">
    allow from all
    Options +Indexes
AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>

     <VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/"
        ServerName xxxxxx.nl
        ServerAlias www.xxxxx.nl
        <Directory "/var/www/">
        allow from all
        Options +Indexes
    AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        </VirtualHost>

        <VirtualHost *:80>
                DocumentRoot "/var/www/giveitatry"
                ServerName giveitatry.nl
                ServerAlias *.giveitatry.nl
                <Directory "/var/www/giveitatry">
                allow from all
                Options +Indexes
            AllowOverride All
                </Directory>
                </VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:12322>
    SSLEngine on
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /usr/share/adminer/adminer
    Alias /adminer/static /usr/share/adminer/adminer/static
    Alias /externals /usr/share/adminer/externals
    Alias /editor   /usr/share/adminer/editor
</VirtualHost>

<Directory /usr/share/adminer/adminer>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

        php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
        php_flag track_vars On
        php_flag register_globals Off
        php_value include_path .
    </IfModule>
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/adminer/editor>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

        php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
        php_flag track_vars On
        php_flag register_globals Off
        php_value include_path .
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Comment: Look like there is problem on client's side. My MacBook works ok with your site. Could you try to execute `nslookup healthcity.giveitatry.nl` on problem Mac?

Comment: Hi Alexander, I am the one with the mac ;) for every nslookup on domain giveitatry.nl, I get the right ip address. For all subdomains, the response is: host healthcity.giveitatry.nl is not found: NXDOMAIN

Comment: I'm able to reproduce this by looking up using google DNS (`dig foo.giveitatry.nl @8.8.8.8` fails), both on OSX and Linux. Looking up www.giveitatry.nl works. http://dnsviz.net/d/foo.giveitatry.nl/dnssec/ has some errors you might want to look into, both the PMTU errors and the NSEC3 errors look relevant.

Comment: @TollefFogHeen Thanks, this looks interesting. I'm not familiar with what this means yet, but I'll find out! keep you posted!

Answer (score 0):

DNS wildcards and DNSSEC do not always play nice together, and you are in this case for your domain. Have a look at http://0skar.cz/dns/en/ to test things, specifically for the computers not able to reach your websites. Also make sure to check which recursive nameserver they are using.